# Where does the ball land and with what speed?

Tags: calculus

A ball is thrown eastward into the air from the origin (in the direction of the positive x-axis).

The initial velocity =  $<50, 0, 80>$

Acceleration = $<0, -4, -32>$

Would it make sense to find the time that the ball lands by setting the z-component of the velocity vector equal to zero. That is, $-32t + 80 =0$, then $t = \frac{5}{2}$ and then plug it into the corresponding vectors?

Comment: When the $z$ velocity hits zero, the ball is at its peak, so to speak. It won't have stopped travelling, however, until it's $z$ velocity is $-80$ by the symmetry of the ball's path.

Comment: @IanColey, by symmetry, the total flight time will be $2 \times \frac{5}{2} = 5$, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, we presume the ground is horizontal, so it lands when $x=0$.  You need to find $z(t)$.  There will be two roots to $z(t)=0$.  One will be $t=0$ as it started at zero elevation.  The other is the one you want.  If you write the equation, $z$ will be quadratic in time, so you use the quadratic formula to find the root.